# After being saved the foreign_key = nil - Solving error in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, controller, foreign-keys, save

I save the @booking with a user (called "booker"). Right after the @booking.save I can retrieve @booking.booker in the command line that display all the properties from the user (email, password, id, etc.). However After leaving the create method, impossible to retrieve it (for example from the show) : @booking.booker = nil . 
I guess that commes from a mistake in my booking model : I have belongs_to and has_many_through. If the error comes from here, how to solve it without having to change all the db?

booking_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:show, :edit, :update ]
  before_action :set_booking_format, only: [:destroy ]
  def index
  end

  def my_bookings
    @bookings = BookingPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, Booking).scope.where(booker: current_user)
  end

  def show
    authorize @booking
  end

  def new
    @garden = Garden.find(params[:garden_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
    authorize @booking
  end

  def create
    @garden = Garden.find params[:garden_id]
    @booking = @garden.bookings.build(booker: current_user)

    authorize @booking
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to garden_booking_path(@booking, current_user)
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  private

  def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_booking_format
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:format])
  end
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:garden_id, :booker_id, :date)
  end
end
```

booking.rb

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :garden
  belongs_to :booker, class_name: "User"
end
```

garden.rb

```
class Garden < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :gardens
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "garden_id"
    t.integer "booker_id"
    t.index ["garden_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_garden_id"
 end

  create_table "gardens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "details"
    t.integer "surface"
    t.text "address"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "availabilities"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "bookings", "gardens"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :gardens
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings
end
```

The `:bookings` association should be `has_many.` You aren't using a join table.

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

The `belongs_to` part of the habtm association is looking for a foreign key, which doesn't exist. You can retrieve `@booking.booker` before moving to a different controller action because you aren't hitting the database at all, you're just retrieving the instance variables' association.

Comment: It gives me the same error when I write has_many instead of has_and_belongs_to_many .